# Avoid inserting duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an application which have a table called Products. My background service is inserting data from an excel file. The problem is taht some times excel file include some duplicate data. My sample statement is,

```
INSERT INTO Products
SELECT Name, Phone, SKU, ModelNumber FROM BlahBlah
```

The problem is that I want to make sure that SKU and ModelNumber should be unique. Means it can be null. But if the value is there then the combination should always be unique. So if there are more than one value of SKU adn ModelNumber then I should only insert the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ Name, Phone, SKU = NULL, ModelNumber = NULL
FROM BlahBlah
WHERE SKU IS NULL AND ModelNumber IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT MAX(Name), MAX(Phone), SKU, ModelNumber 
FROM BlahBlah
WHERE SKU IS NOT NULL OR ModelNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SKU, ModelNumber
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I want to insert all the record which has null/empty SKU and ModelNumber

Comment: With this query, in case there are more records with one combination of (SKU, ModelNumber), you will insert a record which might not correspond to any existing record in BlahBlah.

Comment: @Devart, I want to insert all the record where SKU/ModelNumber is null

Comment: what @BartoszKlimek means is that with this select you can have non-matching `Name` and `Phone`, e.g. `Peter, 238-537, 'Fan', 553` and `Mary, 555-1234, 'Fan', 553`. when you max those, you will get peter with mary's phone number.

Comment: @BrettSchneider, I am sure this will not happen. Beacsue SKU/Model number are always unique.

Comment: @user960567 Do you mean that for given SKU/Model there is only one combination of Name/Phone? If so, the above query could be even simpler. Instead of GROUP BY, you would just need SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 4):

taking into account that maybe you have multiple excel files and already have data in your table and also looking at null-values, try this:

```
INSERT INTO Products
SELECT Name, Phone, SKU, ModelNumber FROM BlahBlah
 where not exists (select * from Products 
                    where coalesce(Products.SKU,'{NULL}') = coalesce(BlahBlah.SKU,'{NULL}')
                      and coalesce(Products.ModelNumber,-1) = coalesce(BlahBlah.ModelNumber, -1)
```

i am assuming SKU is text and ModelNumber numeric. if you want to update the Products table, instead of just not inserting a value when it already exists, try merge:

```
MERGE 
 INTO Products 
USING BlahBlah
   ON coalesce(Products.SKU,'{NULL}') = coalesce(BlahBlah.SKU,'{NULL}')
  and coalesce(Products.ModelNumber,-1) = coalesce(BlahBlah.ModelNumber, -1)
 WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN update set Products.Name = BlahBlah.Name, Products.Phone = BlahBlah.Phone
 WHEN NOT MATCHED 
 THEN insert (Name, Phone, SKU, ModelNumber)
      values (BlahBlah.Name, BlahBlah.Phone, BlahBlah.SKU, BlahBlah.ModelNumber);
```